# What is a viable table structure for an ETL tool when extracting data from a CSV

Tags: database-design, csv, etl

I have started down a rather exciting project. I have had this idea that people in my organisation could drop CSV files into a load folder and then setup a loader in a web interface.

This doesn’t sound that special - however, the beauty is the web app can let the user select only certain columns that they require to be extracted from the CSV - once setup this loader can be run on a regular basis.

The data can then be transformed via a user defined query and potentially loaded into a data wherehouse

The issue I am hitting is a table structure for my staged CSV data - so that I can transform it.

The CSV file structure can vary with lots of columns or very few eg.

```
CLIENT    SALES COST 
Mr Smith  234   45
Mr Blogs  256   35
```

The sturcture I currently have is

```
ID COLUMNID VALUE    FILELOADDATE
1  1        Mr Smith 2012-12-25
2  2        234      2012-12-25
3  3        45       2012-12-25
4  1        Mr Blogs 2012-12-25
5  2        256      2012-12-25
6  3        35       2012-12-25
```

So the data has been 'UNPIVOTED' if you like, allowing me to store various CSV formats

The issue im hitting is now the data has been transposed I have effectively broken the link in that data so I would not know who the sales figure was related to

The approach I have taken is fine if I want to aggregate say sales by date or cost by date or something like that

Is there a different wy I could approach this so that I dont loose that link? could I have another column with row in or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you kind of answer your own question, if you add a row (and maybe a dataset id?, so you can differ between different csv-files). You could then also move the FILELOADDATE field into a dataset table

```
ID DATASETID ROWID COLUMNID VALUE    
1  1         1     1        Mr Smith 
2  1         1     2        234      
3  1         1     3        45       
4  1         2     1        Mr Blogs 
5  1         2     2        256      
6  1         2     3        35
```

Dataset Table:

```
ID FILELOADDATE
1  2012-12-25
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've seen a solution for similar problem. There was:

- one table describing datasets
- one table describing columns (columns of CSV files)
- storage table for data

Columns for dataset description table:

```
ID
FileName
Load_TimeStamp
Name
User
```

Columns for columns description table:

```
ID
dataset_id
ColumnName (csv column name)
ColumnDescription (optional)
StorageColumn (pointing to storage table column name, e.g. "varchar_1"
```

Columns for data table:

```
ID
dataset_id
varchar_1
...
varchar_20
numeric_1
...
numeric_20
```

The point is that you can avoid data transposition (you have to do it several times - on load event and on every manipulation event).